# Rewrite the Json file Using JQuery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, node.js

I have json file in my node project path. According to the backend response i need to update/replace the json in the json file every time dynamically using jquery or javascript. Can anyone help me on this?

Example my data.json file contain is

```
{
    "items" : [
        {
            "fname": "rafael",
            "lname": "marques",
            "age": "19"
        },
        {
            "fname": "daniel",
            "lname": "marques",
            "age": "19"
        }
    ]
}
```

if i get one more item from backend i need to add that item in data.json file.

hw can i achieve this using jQuery or Javascript?

Comment: as i know, you can't modify server file using jQuery or javascript. except you're using javascript based back-end like node.js.

Comment: my project is node.js only

Comment: Can you more specific what is 'from backend' means as nodejs is backend?

Comment: If you need to write to file, you definitely can do it using node.js. http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html

Comment: My -1. "_This question does not show any research effort_; it is unclear or not useful."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very easy to do so. Just try doing this you will get the required output.

```
var initialJson = {
    "items" : [
        {
            "fname": "rafael",
            "lname": "marques",
            "age": "19"
        },
        {
            "fname": "daniel",
            "lname": "marques",
            "age": "19"
        }
    ]
}


var newItem = {
            "fname": "Jack",
            "lname": "marques",
            "age": "20"
        }

initialJson.items.push(newItem);
```

Thanks and regards

Comment: hey @Aniket, are you sure, it will write the value back to the Js file? It doesn't..